MySQL no selected database without setCatalog
I run this query select * from database_name.table_name over JDBC and it fails. It fails with the exception :
SQLTransientConnectionException: (conn=4444889) No database selected
Caused by: MariaDbSqlException: No database selected
Caused by: SQLException: No database selected
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:79)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:158)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:262)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:229)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.execute(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:149)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:163)

When I run setCatalog("database_name") on connection object and run the same query, the query gets executed successfully. Why is this happening? Shouldn't it work anyways since the database name can be read from full identifier in the query.

Your subject line says you are using MySQL, but MySQL doesn't support catalogs. Are you sure you aren't using MariaDB? What does SELECT VERSION(); report?

@BillKarwin the output is 5.7.12-log.

I don't have the MariaDB JDBC driver, but I tested the MySQL Connector/J and I cannot reproduce the issue. I can connect without setting a default database, and query a table using a qualified table name with no error. I don't know why you're using the MariaDB connector if you use MySQL.

MariaDB Connector/J supports MySQL-5.5.3 upward so you could create a CONJ bug report.
